# How to create parent div with opacity while keeping the opacity of the text at 100%

Tags: html, css

So I have a div with an opacity set with a background image. I want the text that pops up when hovering the div to stay 100%. Could anyone possibly help me with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/srfGg/)

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container_inner">
        <div id="container_txt">
            <p><a href="#">WORLD OF WARCRAFT</a></p>
            <p id="p_txt">This is a simple World of Warcraft styled div that has been done implementing html, css, and css3</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I want the text that pops up when hovering the div to stay 100%*

Comment: In the case of your demo, could you not just remove the `opacity` property, and decrease the alpa on the background color? You have already set it with rgba, using an semi-transparent opacity.. So I am confused

Comment: @PastorBones, -Koala I understood the question just now, if you guys see, this is not a duplicate..

Comment: @Mr.Alien this is a duplicate as it is a common problem. Seriously, try googling or using the search box in the top right corner of this site.

Comment: @PastorBones Again, this is not an exact dupe, here we are dealing with opaque image, we cannot use `rgba()` for making an image opaque

Comment: @Mr.Alien In one google search and less than a minute I've found multiple solutions to your question.

Comment: @PastorBones I didn't said that it's not a dupe, there are many out there, the one you linked was not relevant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I fiddled upon and came on conclusion though is this is what you need I think.

> **Below is CSS that you have to use.**

Fiddle: [Click HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/srfGg/1/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srfGg/3/) (Transparent background)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #575980;
}
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #111;
}
#container_inner {
    opacity: .8;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: .5s;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url('http://static.mmo-champion.com/mmoc/images/news/2010/march/ss973.jpg');
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 60% 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#container_inner:hover, #container_txt:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#container_txt {
    color: #fff;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: .2s;
    position: absolute;
    font: normal 1em calibri;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#container_inner:hover #container_txt {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}
p {
    top: -5px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
p a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#p_txt {
    top: -15px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Nice try, but the black popup is not transparent

Comment: okey so you want black popup transparent and the text to be 100 %..Right ??

Comment: Just added the demo to your answer and voted :)

Comment: background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  //Change of opacity !!! ♥

Answer (score 1):

Just for a better understanding:

This CSS changes the opacity of the complete element (background, border, text, containing child-elements, ...)

```
#container{
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But this CSS changes the opacity of a color. And this "modified" color will be used for background.

```
#container{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a child cannot be less opaque than its parent.  In this case, instead of a background image, I would use a :after pseudo element to create the background, then put the background image/opacity/ whatever on that, and leave the parent alone.

I modified your fiddle to do this (http://jsfiddle.net/srfGg/4/), but the main key is:

```
#container_inner:after{
    opacity:0.8;
    transition:.2s;
    content: "";
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: aboslute;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url('http://static.mmo-champion.com/mmoc/images/news/2010/march/ss973.jpg');
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 60% 50%;    
}
#container_inner:hover:after, #container_txt:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```